# Replace apostrophe in JSON with apostrophe suitable for curl via sed

Tags: json, sed, replace, apostrophe

I need to prepare JSON which contains apostrophe to be sent via CURL.
Example of JSON:

```
{"myField":"Apos'test"}
```

Example of JSON I need as an output:

```
{"myField":"Apos'\''test"}
```

What I have tried:

```
sed -e "s/'/'\\\''/g" <<< {"myField":"Apos'test"}
```

which outputs:

```
{myField:Apos'\''test}
```

And I do not understand why it removes double quotes.

P.S. it is not obligatory to use sed, any other standard linux tool would work.

Comment: Use `jq`: `generate_post_data(){jq -n --arg v "$1" '[{ "myField": $v }]'}` and then use `generate_post_data "Apos'test"`

Comment: The sh is removing the double quotes, same as with `echo {"myField":"Apos'test"}`. Try instead `sed -e "s/'/'\\\''/g" <<< "{\"myField\":\"Apos'test\"}"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#/bin/bash
replacement=$((cat << EOT
{"myField":"Apos'test"}
EOT
) | sed "s|'|'\\\''|")
echo $replacement
```

output:

```
{"myField":"Apos'\''test"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't
If it was because you used <<< , here, of which "" pair was parsed, expanded and dropped by the shell you're in

```
$ cat d
{"myField":"Apos'test"}

$ sed -E "s/'/'\\\''/g" d
{"myField":"Apos'\''test"}
```